# INSERT INTO many-to-many table with existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, many-to-many

I'm currently merging two databases to one and facing a problem with a many-to-many table.

I got the following SQL structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Module] (
    ModuleID    INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message] (
    MessageID       INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Size            INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bind] (
    ModuleID        INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Module(ModuleID) NOT NULL,
    MessageID       INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Message(Message) NOT NULL
)
```

[image: Database]

and was already able to insert the values for the tables Module and Message. 
Now i struggle with inserting the existing connections (e.g. ModuleID = 1 with MessageID = 5,1,7,9,6) to the table Bind.

I would like to achieve this with a sql script.

Thank you in advance.

Mady

Comment: Do those relationships exist in one of the source databases? Help us help you. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Comment: Those relationships exist in both source databases. I'm sorry that i didn't post my question in a better format and with the tag RDBMS.

Comment: Not an `RDBMS` tag; a tag for the `RDBMS` that you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query :

```
 INSERT INTO Module (Name) VALUES ('Name 1');
 SET @ModuleID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO Message (Name,Size) VALUES ('Message 1',50);
 SET @MessageID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO Bind (MessageID,ModuleID) VALUES(@ModuleID, @MessageID);
```

Comment: The tables Module and Message are already filled with data. I now need to insert the Bind data from an other database to the new one.